# WCF and custom collections serialization

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, collections, datacontract

I'm sure I'm not the first who asks that question, but I didn't found an answer for me in SO and in Google...

I have a following custom collection:

```
[Serializable]
public class BaseCollection<T>: ICollection<T>
{
}

[CollectionDataContract]
[Serializable]
ProductsCollection : BaseCollection<Product>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I transfer the instance of `ProductsCollection` using WCF...the problem is that WCF not transfers correctly my custom property CategoryId. It always 0 (default of int).

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx they say `CollectionDataContract` should solve it and collection will be serialized to my specific collection and not to ArrayOfProduct.

Am I'm missing something?

If it impossible with DataContract serializer, is it possible to write some kind of MyCustomContract serializer for my specific class that will serialiaze/deserialize my collection as needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContractSerializer` (which is WCF default) serializes only collection items, but no  extra properties.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508229/trouble-with-datacontractserializer/13524894#13524894) for a workaround.

Comment: Hm...it means that I must to create my "collection" that not inherits from ICollectionOfT and there no other solution? Is it possible to write some kind of MyCustomContract serializer for my specific class that will serialiaze/deserialize my collection as needed?

Comment: You could also use `XmlSerializer`, but it seems it's no good either.

Comment: Yep, XmlSerializer is not an option.